# Escape / in the URL context variable

Tags: html, escaping

I am trying to post a request via RestEasy.
Sample URL : http://abc.testusage.com/data1/data2/data3?query=no_mans_land

The variable : data2 = wow/abc
So my request URL becomes :

http://abc.testusage.com/data1/wow/abc/data3?query=no_mans_land

This is failing, since / is treated as URL context.

How do i escape / for this request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using apache you'd want to use something like http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html to rewrite your URL as it comes in so it turns it back into a variable, but if your variables are going to have front slashes in em, good luck with that. Easiest way would be to escape the slashes on the way out to something like %2F

Comment: I have no control over the request URL : http://abc.testusage.com/data1/wow/abc/data3?query=no_mans_land.I need a way to escape / in wow/abc, so that the patterns remains correct. Any suggestions  ?

Comment: Well let's say that data1 is now wow/abc/wow/abc and data2 is wow/abc and data3 is wow/abc/wow/abc/wow/abc so the whole thing becomes wow/abc/wow/abc/wow/abc/wow/abc/wow/abc.... I just don't see how you're going to figure out what's going on at all there. nomsain?